# How to read Riverpod provider inside sentry event processor

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, sentry, riverpod

I am using Sentry + Riverpod and I want to add an `EventProcessor`.
However, necessary data are stored inside providers. How can I read them?

```dart
final myProvider = StateProvider((ref) => 0);

class CustomSentryEventProcessor implements EventProcessor {

  @override
  Future<SentryEvent?> apply(SentryEvent event, {hint}) async {
    return event.copyWith(
      user: (event.user ?? SentryUser()).copyWith(
        extras: {
          'myState': ???, // <-- how to read provider?
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The state is inside the ProviderScope object.  You need a WidgetRef ("ref") to access them through ref.read.

Answer (score 0):

in your case it can be done like this:

```dart
final myProvider = StateProvider((ref) => 0);

class CustomSentryEventProcessor implements EventProcessor {
  CustomSentryEventProcessor(this._ref);

  final Ref _ref;

  Reader get _reader => _ref.read;

  static final pr = Provider<CustomSentryEventProcessor>((ref) => CustomSentryEventProcessor(ref));

  @override
  Future<SentryEvent?> apply(SentryEvent event, {hint}) async {
    return event.copyWith(
      user: (event.user ?? SentryUser()).copyWith(
          extras: {
      'myState': _reader(myProvider), // <-- how to read provider?
      }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and call the method like this:

```dart
class Widget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Widget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    /// ...
    ref.read(CustomSentryEventProcessor.pr).apply(event);
    /// ...
    return ;
  }
}
```